# Populating an AutoComplete with data from relay fails

Tags: reactjs, relayjs

I am trying to populate an autocomplete component with data from relay. It seems pretty straightforward as you can see in the code below. When a fetch is requested I invoke `setVariables` with the search term. Now the behaviour I observe when I type `f` in the input it makes a network request and returns the correct data. However the (controlled) input clears its value (`this.state.value` of the autocomplete component is `''`) and the autocomplete is not populated with the suggestions. Logging the `readyState` show the following output,

[image: logging the ready state object]

```
events: [
  { type: "NETWORK_QUERY_START" },
  { type: "CACHE_RESTORE_START" },
  { type: "CACHE_RESTORE_FAILED" },
  { type: "ABORT" }
]
```

Now entering `f` again in the input it gets the data from relay cache and correctly populates the autocomplete. Entering a second letter though clears the input again and only if enter the two same letters it will get the data and populates the list.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Relay from 'react-relay'
import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest'

const renderSuggestion = (suggestion) => <span>{suggestion.node.fullName}</span>
const getSuggestionValue = (suggestion) => suggestion.node.rowId

class AutoComplete extends Component {
  state = {
    value: '',
  }

  onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
    this.setState({ value: newValue })
  }

  onSuggestionSelected = (event, selection) => {
    console.log(selection)
    this.props.onChange(selection.suggestion)
  }

  onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
    console.log('fetch requested')
    this.props.relay.setVariables({
      query: value,
      hasQuery: true,
    }, (state) => {
      console.log(state)
    })
  }

  onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
    this.props.relay.setVariables({
      query: null,
      hasQuery: false,
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { artists } = this.props.viewer

    const inputProps = {
      onChange: this.onChange,
      placeholder: '...',
      value: this.state.value,
    }

    return (
      <Autosuggest
        suggestions={artists ? artists.edges : []}
        onSuggestionsFetchRequested={::this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
        onSuggestionsClearRequested={::this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
        onSuggestionSelected={::this.onSuggestionSelected}
        getSuggestionValue={getSuggestionValue}
        renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
        inputProps={inputProps}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default Relay.createContainer(AutoComplete, {
  initialVariables: {
    query: null,
    hasQuery: false,
  },

  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Viewer {
        artists: searchArtists(
          first: 10,
          search: $query
        ) @include(if: $hasQuery) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              rowId
              fullName
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  }
})
```

How can I solve this problem. Is this behaviour expected or is this an error on my side or a bug with relay?

**EDIT:** It seems — though I am not sure — that the behaviour I am getting is due to nesting relay containers. Like so `Relay(Profile) -> Form -> Relay(AutoComplete)`.

**EDIT 2:** The input loses its value because `Relay(Profile)` re-renders. Having `shouldComponentUpdate` return `false` for `Relay(Profile)` results in the expected behaviour. However I am guessing thats not the right way to achieve it.